# Generate unique multiple random numbers

Tags: c++, arrays, qt, random

I want to generate unique random numbers and add item in function of these random numbers. Here is my code :

The problem is when i verify if the number generated exist in the array with the code `results.contains(randomNb)` :

```
   int nbRandom = ui->randoomNumberSpinBox->value();
   //nbRandom is the number of the random numbers we want
   int i = 1;
   int results[1000];
   while ( i < nbRandom ){
       int randomNb = qrand() % ((nbPepoles + 1) - 1) + 1;
       if(!results.contains(randomNb)){
           //if randomNb generated is not in the array...
           ui->resultsListWidget->addItem(pepoles[randomNb]);
           results[i] = randomNb;
           //We add the new randomNb in the array
           i++;
       }
   }
```

Comment: ...and your questions is... what?

Comment: You seem to be one step away from having a working solution. All you need is a function that checks if a particular number is in an array (of a particular size). Then you can replace `results.contains(randomNb)` with a call to that function. Is there any reason you can't write that function yourself? Is that what you're asking for help with?

Comment: OOh sorry, i have edited my question ^^

Comment: `results.contains(randomNb)` is not legal C++. That cannot be your code.

Comment: It don't working, that is the question ! Why i should right ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`results` is an array. That's a built-in C++ type. It's not a class type and doesn't have methods. So this can't work:

```
results.contains(randomNb)
```

You probably want to use a QList instead. Like:

```
QList<int> results;
```

Add elements to it with:

```
results << randomNb;
```

Also, you have an off-by-one error in the code. You start counting from 1 (`i = 1`) instead of 0. This will result in missing the last number. You should change the `i` initialization to:

```
int i = 0;
```

With the changes, your code would become:

```
int nbRandom = ui->randoomNumberSpinBox->value();
//nbRandom is the number of the random numbers we want
int i = 0;
QList<int> results;
while ( i < nbRandom ){
    int randomNb = qrand() % ((nbPepoles + 1) - 1) + 1;
    if(!results.contains(randomNb)){
        //if randomNb generated is not in the array...
        ui->resultsListWidget->addItem(pepoles[randomNb]);
        results << randomNb;
        //We add the new randomNb in the array
        i++;
    }
}
```

Comment: Sorry but i am a very bad begeigner at qt and C++, ca you write this in my code ? thanks !

Comment: @RochesterFox Also note the off-by-one error in your code. I updated the answer again.

Comment: Read the docs at http://doc.qt.digia.com/qt/qlistview.html. If you can't figure it out, post a new question. It isn't very difficult though. Just take a bit of time with it :-)